# Load codeigniter environment to a javascript file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using php in my javascript file and my .htaccess looks like

```
<FilesMatch "\.css$">
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
  Header set Content-type "text/css"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.js$">
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
  Header set Content-type "application/javascript"
</FilesMatch>
```

I can now use php from within my javascript files but codeigniter functions do not work.For example

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "<?php $CI = get_instance(); echo base_url(); ?>"
    } );
```

gives the error

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function get_instance() in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\_init\assets\js\custom.js</b> on line <b>88</b><br />
```

I figured maybe i need to load the codeigniter environment in a way similar to the wordpress `require( '../wordpress/wp-load.php' );`

Is there a way i can load codeigniter in a similar manner so that codeigniter functions are available to my javascript and css files?.

Comment: You should also make sure you specifically send no-cache headers along with these "files" so that the browser doesn't cache the CSS an js thinking that the files are typical static files.  Of course this could significantly impact your website performance from the user's standpoint, so really I would question the whole approach to begin with.  For example, there is not reason in the JS snippet, you couldn't define a variable in JS global scope for `sAjaxSource` that could be referenced in a static js file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.I have reconsidered the approach and abandoned the plan all together.In its place,i will just i will just load what i need via the url `"sAjaxSource": 'http://localhost/_init/assets/static_content/arrays.txt'`

Comment: I liked both users SO name :| thats coooolll!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CI relies on the bootstrap  `system/core/CodeIgniter.php` to kick off the application..

There isn't a magic file that you can include that will give you access to the functions..

**Solution 1:** The best solution for your `base_url` problem is to add a base tag [as described by Phil Sturgeon..](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/09/Asset-handling-in-CodeIgniter-with-the-BASE-tag)

`<base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">`

**Solution 2:** define a js base_url in a view

```
<script>
   var base_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
</script>
```

In your js you would access it like..

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": base_url
});
```

**What you are asking for:**

If you rely on CI functions in your js and css, then your approach should be revisited, nevertheless, here is a possible solution..

Create a controller `application/controllers/js.php`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class js extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('js');
    }
}
```

Create a view `application/views/js.php`

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"
});
```

Comment: Since the suggested edit would probably be rejected, you can find an improved version of the third solution [here](https://gist.github.com/HashemQolami/6169106).